# After deleting/removing an array it goes back when refresh

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have two buttons in my tableviewCell which is confirm and ignore these two button should remove the cell when click tho it successfully removing the cell but when i refresh it goes back. How can i permanently removed the data in the array when clicking ignore or confirm.

Firstly the array was solely in activityArray but i need to filter it in order to get the pending activity.

```
        if activities.count > 0 {
            let filtered = activities.filter { $0.activityTypeAction == .FriendRequest || $0.activityTypeAction == .EventRSVPInvite }
            if self.kCurrentPage == 0 {
                self.activityArray.removeAll()
                self.pendingActivityArray.removeAll()
            }
            self.activityArray.append(contentsOf: activities)
            self.pendingActivityArray.append(contentsOf: filtered)
        }
```

This is how i removing the cell.

```
                cell.onClinkedIgnoreCallback = {
                    self.pendingActivityArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    self.NotificationTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
                    self.NotificationTableView.reloadData()
                }
                cell.onClickedConfirmCallback = {
                    self.pendingActivityArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    self.NotificationTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
                    self.NotificationTableView.reloadData()
                }
```

Comment: How you refresh the data? By Navigation from one view to another view or reloading your table view?

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia i'm reloading the tableview. i have this `if (indexPath.row == activityArray.count - 1) { loadMoreActivity() }` where in my loadMoreActivity have the following `if activities.count > 0 {....}` which is provided above code.

Comment: Unrelated but never call `reloadData` right after `deleteRows`. Deleting the rows does update the table view. And there is `isEmpty` for collection types and strings which is more efficient than `.count == 0`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to call that function to refresh because it again fillups the data in the respected arrays so if you want to refresh it just call tableview.reloadData()

Comment: i will not call the loadMoreActivity() ?

Comment: Only once to assign the data to the arrays

Comment: i dont get it. i have ActivityArray then my pendingArray depends on it so eveytime i reload/refresh the view my pendingArray copies my ActivityArray is there a way that my pendingArray will not be affected everytime i refresh?

Comment: put a check on there on pendingarray in the loadMoreActivity() according to your need so it won't update if you not need it to be

Comment: so for example i have this  `let filtered = activities.filter { $0.activityTypeAction == .FriendRequest || $0.activityTypeAction == .EventRSVPInvite }` can i do something like this `filtered.removeAll(where: {$0.activityTypeAction == .FriendAccept} )` then i'll append it `self.pendingActivityArray.append(contentsOf: filtered)`

Comment: hey listen I have an idea Just update the activites array when you remove something then you dont have to apply any of these checks it will just make things complicated

Comment: sorry but how to do that ? if i will remove/update my activities array my recent section in my tableview will be missing a data am i correct ?

Comment: Just remove the particular data by matching the index and then call the  loadMoreActivity()

Comment: but i always don't know what is the index of it. i'm sorry cn you provide a code snippet ir order for me to understand